# How to upgrade my existing application from GWT 2.0 to GWT 2.6

Tags: gwt

How to upgrade my existing application with multiple modules in GWT2.0 to GWT 2.6? I am using Eclipse Kepler and Java version is 7.

Answer (score 8):

1.- If you are considering to make that effort, I would go with 2.7.0 which is the last stable release with many improvements.

2.- There is a long way from 2.0 to 2.6 and 2.7, so I recommend to read all the [release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html) of the versions in the between. Also it is convenient to have the list of [gwt deprecations](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/deprecated-list.html) near

3.- If you are not using a good build system, or you are planning to change it, maybe you can consider to migrate to it before upgrading your project.

4.- Since you are using eclipse Kepler, upgrade it to eclipse Luna with last google-eclipse plugin. And test that everything continues working.

5.- Change your dependencies, so as your project depends on `gwt-user-2.7.0` `gwt-dev-2.7.0` and `gwt-codeserver-2.7.0`. Maybe you are using 3party gwt libraries, you have to check that those libraries continue being active and upgrade them as well.

6.- Open your project in your IDE and try to identify any compilation error. There are no so much changes in the API, but probably you have to select other constructors and methods, like using SafeHtml instead of String etc. Don't forget to look for deprecation warnings as well.

7.- Run your tests an make them pass. Add tests for the modified code.

8.- When everything is green do a full testing in all browsers and fix any issue you can find.

9.- Finally consider migrating certain parts of your app to use new stuff like Cell Widgets, etc.

10.- Change your team habits to start using super-dev-mode instead of classic-dev-mode.

Comment: You should too read all deprecated classes, methods and so on : http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/deprecated-list.html

Comment: @Manolo Carrasco Moñino: Is there any migration guide or document which we can refer to upgrade from GWT 2.0 to 2.7 ?

Comment: Apart from the releases notes, i don't know any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading gwt versions what is need to do is clearly mentioned in this [link](https://javatbrains.blogspot.com/2015/05/error-while-installing-gwt-plugin-in.html)

Recently I upgraded my hole project GWT from 2.4.0 to 2.6.0, I faced lot of problems from scratch. Finally I did it by referring the above link and some other gwt websites.

If still you have any queries, write in comment, I will do my help.

Comment: link is broken!

Comment: Thanks for informing me. I updated it to the correct page.